# по нажатию на input сформировать маску телефона

Tags: html, jquery

Через jquery сформировать маску вида +7(  )

Answer (score 2):

[maskedinput.js](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

```js
$('.js-phone').mask("+7(999)999-9999");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="js-phone" placeholder="Телефон" >
```

Comment: Хуквери-плюгины - наше всё, да?

Comment: @Other, именно )

Comment: @Other, так и вопрос про них

Comment: @Grundy, протестую, вопрос о "Сделайте мне", что **может** включать плюгины, вместо нормального, быстрого и качественно формирования.

Comment: @Other, "Через jquery сформировать маску вида +7( )" ...  через jquery

Comment: ... И не вижу тут требование плюгинов.

Comment: Ладно, хватит флудить.

Comment: @vp_arth, а у меня как? http://prntscr.com/ekbio9

Comment: @vp_arth, правильно или нет, будет решать автор, а вы можете свой ответ написать

Comment: @Elena, я вижу проблему в том, что автор получит готовый ответ до того, как переформулирует свой вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте плагин jquery inputmask
https://plugins.jquery.com/jquery.inputmask/